# SQL server Named pipe Issue

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

[image]I have desktop application with .net framework 2.0 now we are migrating to sql server 2014. My desktop app developed in C# throws me this error while running project.

> a connection was successfully established with the server but then an error
>   occured during the login process .(provider named pipes provider, error = no process 
>   is on the other end of the pipe

I checked sql server settings named pipe is enabled.

Can you please suggest what should I do ?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Did you try googling for the error message? There *are* a lot of results for this specific error, many of them from SO

Comment: well most of them are about to enable named pipe line which is already enabled

Comment: Or about connecting to the *correct* server/instance. In any case, without providing any information, it's impossible to help.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your Sql Server configuration manager showing named pipes is available? Also are you trying to connect to a server on the same machine as your program or different machine, if it is a different machine try enabling TCP/IP and see if that helps (be sure to check the windows firewall too for TCP/IP is allowing inbound connections to the sql server instance).

Comment: my program is connecting from different machine on same network its intranet desktop application

Comment: just added screen shot

Answer (score 0):

i think problem is that named pipes and TCP/IP connection is not enabled. please go through below link and follow the procedure step by step.

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/21/sql-server-fix-error-provider-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-microsoft-sql-server-error/